# What type of motor (size, type, approx cost) would be best to use to open a bedroom window

Tags: servomotor

I noticed a tag showed up that indicates a servomotor. This looks like what I want. My new question is what size of a servomotor do I need to move a window that is approx 3 feet by 2 ft 8 inches.Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* lonestarkid, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: probably the same type of motor that can open a kitchen window .... seriously though, `bedroom` is irrelevant ... window type is relevant

Comment: I hope this is the place to respond.. it is not clear... I am the author of the question..lonestarkid...  ok I will try this again... what size and type of motor will be strong enough to move a window that is 3ft by 2 feet 8 inches . I know nothing about motors thanks!!